# C++ OpenMP parallel with a read-only reference variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, openmp, parallel.for

I'm trying to run code in parallel with the GCC 4.4.7 version. I used the OpenMP library. I have a read-only variable (pointer to a class) which is shared by all the threads.

The code is compiled and executed without any errors, but I do not obtain the same results when running the same code in a serial sequence (the results in the serial mode are true).
The code looks like:

```
#include <class1>
#include <class2>
int main(){
    string a;
    int b1,b2,d;
    class1 c1(a,b1);
    c1.compute(d);
    int n_thread = 10; 
    int i,n=10;
    vector<vector<int> > res(n);
    omp_set_dynamic(0);            
    omp_set_num_threads(n_thread);   

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(n_thread) private(i)  shared(res) 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        class1 c(c1.tab,b2);
        c.compute(d);

        class2 toto(b1,b2);
        toto.getvect(c1.tab,c.tab);//Inside toto, the c1.tab is read-only 

        #pragma omp critical
        {
            res[i] = vector<int> (toto.p);
        }
    }
//the rest of the program when I use the c1 var and the res matrix.
}
```

My first thought was that the problem is from the two reference variables *c* and *toto*, but these two variables are created at each thread, so they are private to each thread.
I tried to use *c1* as *threadprivate* but there was a compilation error. If *c1* is declared as shared, there is no change at the output results. Maybe the problem is from the multiple acces to the smae variable at the same time ? How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: You're pushing results onto a shared vector. This will be *absolutely* non-deterministic, and the results will come out in any order. If that's what you mean by 'the results aren't the same'. If not, you need to specify what you mean by 'the results are different'.

Comment: I mean by the results: the results of my algorithm and not the matrix _res_. No matter if the vectors of the _res_ matrix come out in any order, The most important is, each vector will be stored as a block and its values will not be mixed with another vector.

Comment: Without seeing the code of that algorithm, it's hard to debug a problem with it, especially a concurrency problem. Also, it looks like you could have other consistency violations around the `b` variables as it seems like they're being manipulated inside the parallel code, and not even in a `critical` block. Still, seeing some example input and expected output vs. actual output would be helpful (edit into the original question).

Comment: I do not think there is a problem with a _critical_ block. The same code runs well under the visual studio 2012 on windows 7, but it does not run correctly under lunix GCC4.4.7.

Comment: @aruisdante, he's not pushing results onto a shared vector. He's writing it like a c array since he already allocated the memory for the vector. There is no need for critical in this case either.

Comment: I don't see what is being calculated differently each iteration. It look's like it calculates the same value every iteration. Are you modifying `c1`, `b1`, `b2`, or `d` each iteration? If so then obviously you won't get the same result since they are shared.

Comment: At each iteration, _class1 c(c1.tab,b2)_ takes a radom subset of elements from _c1.tab_ and continues the calculation, the different parameters _c1_, _b1_, _b2_ and _d_ are the same at each iteration (so each iteration repeats the same calculation but on different subsets of data). By running the code on VS2012, I get the results that I want, but under Linux, I do not know what it happens between threads, like all the results are merged in incomprehensible way.